# Is it possible to render two models in one controller

Tags: playframework

I am using play as a framework, is it possible to render two different models in one controller application?

Comment: Yes, possible. But could you specify more concrete what your problem is? Otherwise for such generic question it is hardly to give more precise answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is you just need to define it something like in this example

@(con:models.cassadra.kundera.Content,fileName:String,discounts:java.util.List[models.cat.dbl.mysql.ContentDiscounts])